# How to make Common code and vars in React

Tags: reactjs

We have created a GeneralForm in React which accepts a json of fields with their properties: name, type, min/max values etc.)

the GeneralForm have created a form with all relevant inputs.

The GeneralForm also managed the state with map for all the fields.

And did other logic as well: disable/enable fields according to the definitions in the json and the values the user input.

Now, we have some more complicated forms, with variant designs, so we want to create the form, as static form, without using the GeneralForm.
We are also afraid building complicated forms on runtime will cause slowness in the application.

The thing is, we still want to reuse the state management of the GeneralForms and the logic of enabled/disabled.
Any ideas how we can implment this?

In OOP the GeneralForm would have been Abstract to all forms, but since React is functional oriented, we can't do it.

Another option is to leave the GeneralForm and make support this different variant forms somehow - but we are not sure it worth the work.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking, but, from what I understand, you want to re-use a state across multiple components that are not strictly hierarchical? It sounds like you should look into using either a [reducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) or perhaps even adding the quite-a-bit-more-verbose [React Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/).

Comment: The other way I interpret this question, is that you want the Java-equivalant of an abstract class that all your React-components will inheret from. For that you can simply re-use GeneralForm as a component that you pass different props to, or add new classes that use the component in different ways.

Comment: I meant to use  Java-equivalant of an abstract class. Reducer /Redux is not enough, since I have extra common code I want to share in all forms. I didnt understand your solution of using the GeneralForm as a component - how will recognize the state of all fields, and how I can add a callback of onchange to all fields through him.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment above, I suggested that you could use a common component accross several other components, as such:

```
import React from 'react'

const commonFields = {
  field1: {
    id: 1,
    name: "e-mail",
    type: "email"
  },
  field2: {
    id: 2,
    name: "password",
    type: "password"
  }
}

export default function App() {
  
  function submitHandleExtended(formData) {
    // handle form data
  }

  function submitHandleAlternative(formData) {
    // handle form data
  }

  return <div>
    <ExtendedForm formId="extended" fields={commonFields} submitHandler={submitHandleExtended}/>
    <AlternativeForm formId="alternative" fields={commonFields} submitHandler={submitHandleAlternative}/>
  </div>
}

function CommonForm({formId, fields, submitHandler}) {
  return <form id={formId} onSubmit={submitHandler}>
    {Object.keys(fields).map(key => {
      const field = fields[key]
      return <div key={field.id}>
        <label htmlFor={field.id}>{`${field.name}`}</label> <br />
        <input type={field.type} id={field.id} name={field.name} /><br />
      </div>
    })}
  </form>
}

function ExtendedForm({formId, fields, submitHandler}) {
  return <div>
    <CommonForm formId={formId} fields={fields} submitHandler={submitHandler} />
    <input type="submit" value={"Submit"} form={formId}/>
  </div>
}

function AlternativeForm({formId, fields, submitHandler}) {
  return <div>
    <CommonForm formId={formId} fields={fields} submitHandler={submitHandler} />
    <label htmlFor="fileId">Add file</label>
    <input id="fileId" type="file" form={formId}/> <br />
    <input type="submit" value={"Submit"} form={formId}/>
  </div>
}
```

Here you can use `CommonForm` inside all other forms, which would work similar to an abstract/open class.

Comment: To add to this, what I've proposed is using composition instead of inheritance (differences are detailed [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) and [here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/react.js-and-inheritance)).